# HDMI/VGA/NTSC/PAL to 24-bit parallel RGB interface

Tags: lcd, tft, hdmi, ntsc

[Adafruit.com](http://adafruit.com/) is selling [TFT-LCD modules that comes with an NTSC/PAL driver board](http://www.adafruit.com/category/63_110). The product specification page includes a link to the [original manufacturer´s datasheet/specifications for the TFT itself (without the NTSC/PAL driver board)](http://www.panelook.com/TD020THEG1_TPO_2.0_LCM_overview_12367.html). As the displays sold at [Adafruit.com](http://adafruit.com/) are unecessarily (i think) expensive, and I want to buy [one at eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/4-3inch-480x272-Touch-LCD-B-4-3-TFT-Display-Module-Graphic-LCM-Screen-Panel-/251173169883?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a7b166adb) instead, but I can't find any NTSC/PAL driver board for the 24-bit parallel RGB interface. I found a board that lets you connect a HDMI-transmitting device to a LVDS TFT-LCD, but those LVDS display often cost more than I plan to spend on a TFT.

What kind of board/chip should I be looking for if I want to connect a HDMI/VGA/NTSC/PAL device to a 24-bit parallel TFT-LCD?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: Roll your own driver if you want for the learning experience, but there is no way you will save money doing so unless you plan on making them in quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a many ICs on the market for decoding video signals. For digital interfaces there is for example the ADV7611. For VGA and Composite/S-Video/Component Analog Devices also have Decoder/Receiver such as ADV7182 and ADV7401.
These ICs are also used on many LVDS Converters. But you have to design the PCB on your own, and especially for HDMI this is not that easy.